Отступ в шаблоне Wordpress
не могу разобраться от куда взялся отступ в шаблоне страницы ( отметил красным ) при просмотре кода страницы, ничего подобного с таким отступом нет.И данный белый блок никак не выделяется что бы посмотреть что это. 

С картинками - к телепатам. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Это не шаблон ВП. Это похоже шаблон какой-то мышевозки (элементор или что-то типа того)
